# AngularJs Material (or maybe just css in general)- How do I align columns between rows?

Tags: css, flexbox, material-design, angular-material, html-lists

To give an example of what I mean, let's say I have three data points I want to display- Name, title, office. This is a bad example since these things are typically self descriptive, but say I want to lay them out like:

```
Name: [name]       Office: [office]
Title: [title]
```

Additionally, I will have a list of several people who will each be displaying these attributes.

Right now, what I'm trying to do is make the "Name:/Title:" into a column the "[name] [title]" into a column, the "Office:" into a column, and the "[office]" into a column. The problem is that quickly becomes unwieldy, having related data be in drastically different places in the HTML, and leads to potential desyncing of the information to the headers (e.g. if one row wraps, then all rows below it will be offset from the header by 1 line size). I ALSO want to make sure that the column locations are the same between different users (So someone named "Bob" and someone named "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt" would both have their "Office:" column aligned despite their names being different lengths).

What is the recommended approach for something like this? Trying to use AngularJS Material, would I use an md-grid despite it not really being homogenous tiled information? Or is these a more obvious approach that I'm just not seeing using the layout-align properties with regular containers? Or is the better approach just to use custom css to set more rigid locations for the header columns and just let the data flex accordingly?

Alternatively, is there just a better recommended styling for displaying this sort of information, that's more "material design"ish? Note that the headers are 100% required because it may not be immediately obvious what each piece of data is representing due to the nature of the data I'm actually working with (e.g. I'm displaying both office and mobile numbers, so I need a clear way to differentiate the two), but if there's a better way to organize those header/data pairings, I'm all for investigating that route.

EDIT: Here's a snippet of code (edited to remove any actual data/functionality, but just to get the gist across). This is a WIP so it's not intended to be nice, but I can already tell that this approach isn't going to work out at all.

```
            <md-list-item>
                    <div layout="column">
                        <md-button class="md-button" ng-click="placeholder">
                            <a layout="row" >
                                [Name]
                            </a>
                            <div layout="row" layout-align="center">
                                [Title]
                            </div>
                        </md-button>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="row">
                        <div layout="column">
                            <div layout="row">
                                Mobile:
                            </div>
                            <div layout="row">
                                Office: 
                            </div>
                            <div layout="row">
                                E-mail: 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div layout="column">
                            <div layout="row">
                                [mobile]
                            </div>
                            <div layout="row">
                                [office]
                            </div>
                            <div layout="row">
                                <a href="mailto:[email]" class="one-place-link">[email]</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div layout="column">
                            <div layout="row">
                                Field1: 
                            </div>
                            <div layout="row">
                                Field2: 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div layout="column">
                            <div layout="row">
                                [field1]
                            </div>
                            <div layout="row">
                                [field2]
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
            </md-list-item>
```

This is semi-workable on a per-item basis, but the alignment between items is non-existent with this approach. The first column (name and title) is anywhere from 100px to 250px wide for different users, and the second column (phone numbers and e-mail) directly follow  suit, and it looks really messy. Additionally, the loose pairing between the headers and the data make expanding this inconvenient, and make optional properties that can be turned off in the settings awful to maintain, since I have to check the settings for both the header and the data.

EDIT2: https://jsfiddle.net/pb2gqLm6/

Here's an example of what I mean. I would like the "Office:/Mobile:Email:" column to be aligned across ALL of the users, instead of being offset based on the name length. I know I can do it with set column sizes and/or percentage widths, but I'm wanting to know if there's a better approach I should be taking here.

Comment: This seems - at first glance - relatively easy to implement (many things are, once you know how to do them); but could you share your current HTML so that we know what you're working with in order that we can offer answers that are directly useful to you? See the "*[mcve]*" guidelines, if you haven't already read them.

Comment: I edited the original comment to add in a stripped down sample of my code. Hopefully you can kinda see what I'm going for here. In the meantime I'll work on getting a sample plunkr or something up just in case.

Comment: Alright, I've also added a plunker to the description, hopefully you can better see where I'm coming from now.

Comment: So the 'name' and 'title' should occupy the column (or 'box') to the left; the second column should be composed of 'mobile', 'office' and 'email' (with the relevant data beside them) and additional rows/fields should occupy columns to the right? And how tied to that specific HTML are you, can it be changed?

Comment: This entire thing is a work in progress to get used to how I'd do layout using AngularJS/Material Design/flexbox. The library we currently have in production is SemanticUI, which allows each item to be its own grid, but it separates it into 16 equally spaced columns to ensure consistency between them (so effectively percentage-width solution now that I think about it). But yes, the entire thing can be scrapped and redone as long as I get all the data laid out in a readable, maintainable, properly aligned way.

Comment: I wrote this, using CSS grid, because I didn't properly read your previous comment; if it's of any use to you I'll write a proper answer and, if I'm able, write up a flexbox solution. Obviously if there's any problems with the demo implementation point them out and I'll address those :) demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mLvdxj1z/

Comment: I had actually already begun research into css grid, and it does look like it's far easier to get the behavior I want there. Your solution is very nice, and went above and beyond with the media queries! I still need to look into how intermixed I can make this with the AJSM framework, but I've read that it's not too uncommon to have CSS Grid define containers and 2d positioning, and having flex define the actual horizontal or vertical (1d) layout within those containers. I definitely have enough to tinker with at this point, though, so thanks a ton for your help!